# Reconocer ID's de un MainActivity principal en un MapsActivity

Tags: java, android-studio

Estoy realizando un ejercicio de prueba, donde al pulsar un botón de la primera actividad me envíe al MapsActivity y en esa Activity (MapsActivity) me reconozca el ID del botón pulsado y me muestra unas coordenadas específicas, y si regreso y oprimo el segundo botón, me muestre otras coordenadas en el mismo MapsActivity, estuve probando algunas opciones y no logré solucionarlo. Este es el código que he venido manejando.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Button button;
    private Button button2;
    private final int PETICION_ACTIVITY_SEGUNDA = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()){

        case R.id.button:
            Intent intent= new Intent (MainActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            break;

        case R.id.button2:
            Intent intent1= new Intent (MainActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
            break;

    }

}
}
```

MapsActivity:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, View.OnClickListener {
private GoogleMap mMap;
public Button button1;
public Button button2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
}

/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera

    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.button:
                    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(4.657923, -74.059470);
                    LatLng sydney1 = new LatLng(4.657998, -74.059429);



                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 18));

                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin)).position(sydney));
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin)).position(sydney1));

                    break;

                case R.id.button2:
                    LatLng sydney2 = new LatLng(4.658035, -74.059365);
                    LatLng sydney3 = new LatLng(4.658078, -74.059301);
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin)).position(sydney2));
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin)).position(sydney3));

                    break;

            }

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para eso se utiliza `bundle`.
Envías `String` y `double` en el `intent`, en este caso con `putExtra`:

```
 case R.id.button:
        String valorString = "Boton 1";
        double valorDouble1 = 4.657923;
        double valorDouble2 = -74.059470;

        Intent intent= new Intent (MainActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("KeyString", valorString);
        intent.putExtra("KeyDouble1", valorDouble1);
        intent.putExtra("KeyDouble2", valorDouble2);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;

    case R.id.button2:
        String valorString = "Boton 2";
        double valorDouble1 = 4.658078;
        double valorDouble2 = -74.059301;

        Intent intent1= new Intent (MainActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
        intent1.putExtra("KeyString", valorString);
        intent1.putExtra("KeyDouble1", valorDouble1);
        intent1.putExtra("KeyDouble2", valorDouble2);
        startActivity(intent1);
        break;
```

Y los recibes en onCreate del Maps Avtivity de esta forma:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String stringRecibido = bundle .getString("KeyString");
    double doubleRecibido1 = bundle .getDouble("KeyDouble1");
    double doubleRecibido2 = bundle .getDouble("KeyDouble2");
```

De esta forma también envias las coordenadas. Si nada mas quieres saber que boton fue pulsado
entonces en tu MapActivity, agrega un if/else en onMapReady y elimina el onClick:

```
 if(stringRecibido.equals("Boton 1")){
        ...agregas las coordenadas y los markers...
    }else {  // en este caso sería el Boton 2
        ...agregas las coordenadas y los markers...
    }
```

Comment: Hola armen, gracias por tu colaboración me funcionó como deseaba, aunque no coloque el Bundle en el onCreate del MapsActivity, sino en el OnMapReady, para poder visualizar los markets en el mapa y no tuvo ningún inconveniente, espero que esta misma función pueda servir en un Navigation Drawer